# Android Leanback: Reduce rows spacing in RowsSupportFragment

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I'm trying to create a vertical list of selectable items in Android TV using Leanback RowsSupportFragment. There seems to be some default spacing, shown as black color in attachment, between rows here. I need to remove this spacing.  I've looked into some **dimens** attributes but they are setting the spacing globally while I only require it on a particular screen. How this may be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `setVerticalMargin` (or `setItemMargin` ?) methods of the VerticalGridView widget in RowsSupportFragment:

```
getVerticalGridView().setVerticalMargin(25);
```